# How to pass all files from folder as parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, coffeescript

How is it possible to dynamically load all files in folder and pass them as argument to program?

Now I have to do

```
coffee --bare --join app.js -c utils.coffee app.coffee forum.coffee items.coffee models.coffee activate.coffee chat.coffee
```

while, all .coffee files should be loaded automatically, so when I add new file I don't have to edit my script.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arguments = [string]::join(" ",(get-item *.coffee | foreach { $_.Name }))
Invoke-Expression (".\program.exe {0}" -f ($arguments))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute your command like this:

> &coffee --bare --join app.js -c $(gci *.coffee)

Answer (score 0):

You can all all of the files to a string using the following

```
get-childitem *.coffee | Join-String -Separator " "
```

Then use [start-process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx) to invoke the command

### EDIT

If you dont have the powershell community extension you can use

```
[string]::join(" ",(gci))
```

Comment: -join operator works in powershell v2+ -- so @(1,2,3) -join " "

Comment: @x0n so it is $argus= @(gci folder/*.pdf) -join ','; merge-pdf $argus -outputfile out.pdf as I want to merge pdfs into one.